# magento adding custom column to eav_attribute table

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want adding my custom field(column in database) to table `eav_attribute`
this is my configuration models and resource in t

```
 <models>
    <mycompany_filters>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mycompany_filters_resource</resourceModel>
    </mycompany_filters>
    <mycompany_filters_resource>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model_Resource</class>
    </mycompany_filters_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <mycompany_filters_setup>
        <module>Mage_Eav</module>
        <module>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</module>
    </mycompany_filters_setup>
</resources>
```

directory tree

---

```
sql
 -- mycompany_filters_setup
  -- install-0.1.4.php
```

and content file install-0.1.4.php

---

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 
    "is_used_in_category", 
    "TINYINT( 1 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'"
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

but this doesn't work. In table `core_resource` not create string resource for `mycompany_filters` and in table `eav_attribute` don't created new column.

Error logs: system.log and exception.log apache2 log is empty

Main question why is doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to point out a few things I think is wrong here.

First your `config.xml`:

```
<models>
    <mycompany_filters>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mycompany_filters_resource</resourceModel>
    </mycompany_filters>
    <mycompany_filters_resource>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model_Resource</class>
    </mycompany_filters_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <mycompany_filters_setup>
        <module>Mage_Eav</module>
        <module>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</module>
    </mycompany_filters_setup>
</resources>
```

Should really be:

```
<models>
    <mycompany_filters>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mycompany_filters_resource</resourceModel>
    </mycompany_filters>
    <mycompany_filters_resource>
        <class>Mycompany_Filters_Model_Resource</class>
    </mycompany_filters_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <mycompany_filters_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Mage_Eav</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <!-- You could add these as well
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        -->
    </mycompany_filters_setup>
    <!-- If you add the connection tag above, you should add these as well
    <filters_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </filters_write>
    <filters_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </filters_read>
    -->
</resources>
```

Essentially, you are missing the `<setup>` tag that should wrap the resources `<module>` and `<class>` tags.

The contents of `install-0.1.4.php` should instead be:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getTable('eav/attribute');
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($table, 'is_used_in_category', array(
            'type'      => 'could be Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT or any you want it should be',
            'nullable'  => true, //could be true or false
            'default'   => null, //default value for this attribute
            'unique'    => true, //could be true or false
            'comment'   => 'Your comment here. Not important'
        ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

In your `config.xml`, make sure the version declared is same as `0.1.4`. **Clear your CACHE after these changes and run your application**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I don't user cache in process development.

Comment: and  this `<module>Mage_Eav</module>` should be `<module>Mycompany_Filters</module>` thanks again for help me

Comment: Maybe you know event before save eav attribute

Comment: Magento dispatches two different events before saving any model and the eav isn't any exception. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute` extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract` which in turn extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. In the _beforeSave() method of the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, two events are dispatched. One, `model_save_before` and the other, `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before'`, where `$this->_eventPrefix` is essentially `eav_entity_attribute` for the eav model. So, you could hook either into `model_save_before` or `eav_entity_attribute_save_before` event. Cheers :)

Comment: thanks again I search over event in controller predispath, but I think your variant better